# Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to check if some column of specify user is holding a value higher than 0.

**Problem**

When doing the query, and ***then executing it***, Im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\admin\create.php on line 40
```

My code (The query + execute):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $admin = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username");
        $admin->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
        $admin->execute();
```

Line of error (40):

```
if ($settings['create_admins'] > 0 || $admin['super_admin'] > 0 ) {
```

**Question:**

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

I tried doing this:

```
$admin = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username");
$admin = $admin->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
$admin = $admin->execute();
```

and getting another error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\admin\create.php on line 38
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I need the ->fetch object, but I have just done this, and got rid of the errors.. But it doesn't affect? I mean I am echoing that row, and it gives me a null (nothing). Why?

```
$admin = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['user']."");
$admin = $admin->fetch();
```

Comment: There're many examples in the PHP manual on how to retrieve rows with PDO. There's absolutely no need to guess.

Comment: I think the error is here $admin = $admin->execute(); you don't need to assigned back the result of execute() to $admin variable, just call the execute()

Comment: Make `var_dump($admin)` after `$admin = $admin->fetch();` and see the output.

Comment: If I will remove the $admin = before $admin->, I will get the same error.

Comment: @Narek I am getting bool(false)

Comment: @JonyKale then probably you have problem with query. Change `prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ".$_SESSION['user']."");` with `prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'");`

Comment: Yes, that's it! Just needs query instead of prepare, thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From:

```
$admin = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username");
[...]
if ($settings['create_admins'] > 0 || $admin['super_admin'] > 0 ) {
```

`$admin` is of type `PDOStatament` which is a class and not an array. Therefore you can't call the `[]` operator on it.

Also you should really not alway assign `$admin` to the return result of every method because most of the `PDOStatament`'s methods return boolean values:

```
$admin = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = :username");
$admin->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
$admin->execute();
```

To retrieve the `super_admin` column from the `admin` table you should add (after the `execute()` statement):

```
$result = $admin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

which will populate (hopefully, it depends on what's the table schema) `$result['super_admin']`.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $CONNECT_TO_DATABASE->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']));
$admin = $stmt->fetch();
if($admin) {
   //do something if query returns row(s)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by if ($admin) ? All I want to do is fetch the data from that specify user's row.

Comment: the if admin is just a fall back if your query does not return any row, so that $admin[somefield] will not return an error